# MongoWriteConcernException. the (immutable) field '_id' was found to have been altered to _id

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

While making update in MongoDB in CodeIgniter I have the following error:

```
Type: MongoWriteConcernException

Message: localhost:27017: After applying the update to the document {_id: ObjectId('55ee98543bd7af780b000029') , ...}, the (immutable) field '_id' was found to have been altered to _id: "55ee98543bd7af780b000029"

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\CI\application\models\mongo_model.php
```

Here is my controller code

```
public function  update()
{
    $userdata['firstname'] = $this->input->post('txtfirstname');
    $userdata['lastname'] = $this->input->post('txtlastname');
    $userdata['email'] =  $this->input->post('txtemail');
    $userdata['password'] = md5($this->input->post('txtpassword'));
    $userdata['_id'] = $this->input->post('hiddenId');
    $collection=  $this->mongo_model->updateuserdb($userdata);
    if ($collection)
    {
        header('location:'.base_url()."index.php/user".$this->index());
    }
}
```

and model code is

```
public function updateuserdb($userdata)
{
    $id = $userdata['_id'];
    $collection = $this->mongo_db->db->selectCollection('myfirstCollection');
    $query = $collection->update(array('_id' => new MongoId($id)), array('$set' => $userdata), array('upsert' => FALSE));
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: How is the error message not explanation enough? The `_id` field is "immutable" which means you cannot change the value. If you have any familiarity with databases in general then "altering a primary key" should be a general concept you understand cannot be done.

Comment: Even if the value is the same you must remove the _id field from the update document else this error will occur

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You cannot update the `_id` field.

Notice that your `$userdata` object variable contains the `_id` field and then you proceed to pass that `$userdata` object as the value to be updated. As a result, you are attempting to update the `_id` field.

You need to remove the `_id` from `$userdata` when doing **'$set'=>$userdata**.

```
$collection->update(array('_id'=>new MongoId($id)),array('$set'=>$userdata),array('upsert'=>FALSE));
```

Comment: thanks for the answer I really make that  funny mistake